# alloc-init sometimes fails in program

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am bothered by the following code snippet in my program.

If I write

```
mo=[[myObj alloc] init];
```

it fails, but if I write

```
mo=[myObj alloc];
mo=[mo init];
```

it works. These two methods are supposed to be equivalent but somehow I am messing up. Any light?

Clarifications:

myObj is the name of a class

It fails by trying to allocate for a different kind of object, failing to find the right methods and finally crapping out far from the initialization.

Comment: Is myObj the name of a class? A common nubie mistake is to put the name of the instance in the alloc. Is it a custom class or do you see the same problem with Foundation classes. What error gets return?

Comment: In what way does it fail? i.e. what happens differently in your program between the first method and the second one?

Comment: Agreed. You need to give more information about *how* it's failing.

Comment: And showing the code for `init` wouldn't hurt, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may happen only when the `-(id)init` method is overwriten wrong in the `myObj` Class.
Maybe you don't `return self;` or you don't have the returning type `(id)`. If none of this is right, please provide more details about how the `-(id)init` method is implemented.

Comment: +1 from me. This sounds like a good guess as to why it would fail only in the one case. Good thinking!